# How can I select a word under a cursor position in Kate via shortcut?

Tags: cursor, selection, cpu-word, textselection, kate

During programming I have to often select a whole word and make delete it. I am doing this by double click in mouse, but i prefer do it by keyboard - it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, removing the word to the left/right is done with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

There is also <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, which selects the word under the cursor. May also be handy if you want to delete it. But originally, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> was added as search for word under cursor (i.e., pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> again will jump to the next instance).

Comment: Kate shortcuts ctrl+backspace ctrl+delete remove/delete **part of the word** left/right from the cursor position within the word, not the neighbor word to the left/right *(phrase "removing the word to the left/right suggests an entire word will be removed)*. Best you update your answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a Kate IDE right now to test, but these two should work, they are kind of universal.

```
Ctrl+Backspace – Delete previous word
Ctrl+Delete    – Delete next word
```

You could also just select a word left or right from the cursor with the following short keys

```
Shift+Ctrl+Left or Right Arrow Keys – Select words respectively left or right from the cursor
```

Using the short keys in a middle of the word you will delete respectively the left or the right part of the word.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+Left or Right Arrow Keys works as described by you - i was thinking about selecting whole word with cursor inside before, but now I think it will even more fit my needs -  can select prefix and sufix.

Ctrl+Backspace and Ctrl+Delete works like selection by Shift+Ctrl+Left or Right and delete one part of word (left or right). 
Thanks.